# Loading Handlebars template via AJAX returns document object instead of string

Tags: ajax, handlebars.js

I'm loading this Handlebars.js template:

```
<ul></ul>
```

with AJAX using the following code

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'collection.handlebars',
    success : function (data) {
        Handlebars.templates["collection"] = Handlebars.compile(data);
    },
    async : false
});
```

The template compilation fails with the following message in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: You must pass a string to Handlebars.compile. You passed [object Document]
```

After debugging I noticed that the `data` returned in the success callback is an HTML document and not a string.  However, if I change the template to:

```
<ul></ul> &nbsp
```

the `data` in the success callback is received as a string and everything works.

I'm using Handlebars 1.0 RC2 and Chrome 24.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain what the step  
"Handlebars.templates["collection"] = Handlebars.compile(data);" is doing here? I am facing a similar issue where i have to pass data form ajax to a handlebar template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the datatype for the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'collection.handlebars',
    success : function (data) {
        Handlebars.templates["collection"] = Handlebars.compile(data);
    },
    dataType: "text",
    async : false
});
```