# Ajax web app works from various Fedora servers but not from Ubuntu server

Tags: jquery, apache, ubuntu

I have an AJAX web application which uses jQuery 1.7.1, backbone 0.9.2, and handlebars 2.0.0 alpha.  There are several instances running on servers - the oldest is Fedora 13 with Apache 2.2.16, the newest is Fedora 19 with Apache 2.4.4.  It also runs on Ubuntu Lucid.  However, on newer version of Ubuntu (oneric, precise, trusty beta 1) I get jQuery unhandled exceptions.  I have check all my PHP fetches and they all look fine.

I am not asking anyone to fix my code, but I don't understand how code running in the browser can be broken by the server.  I can only think of Apache being the culprit, but I have it working on a range of Apache versions including those used in the newer Ubuntu servers.

I would really appreciate any suggestions for what might be the cause.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to do some more research in your browser's developer console. Most likely, one of your installations is incorrectly configured or deployed, leading to the failure of one or more scripts to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue already answered on SO:

[Loading Handlebars template via AJAX returns document object instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733756/loading-handlebars-template-via-ajax-returns-document-object-instead-of-string)

However, I still don't understand how it was working under Fedora but not Ubuntu, with the same versions of Apache etc.

Does anyone have any ideas?